# PyQT5 QScrollBar within QDockWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea, qdockwidget

I have a lot of buttons, lineedits and other widgets in a window. Because they are too much for one window, I like to wrap them in a QScrollArea. All that should be in a QDockWindow. My problem: the docker window is visible and works, but none of the buttons and no scroll bar is visible.
I'm using python 3.6 / PyQT5
My code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pprint import pprint

class DockWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DockWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout=QHBoxLayout()
        
        self.docker = QDockWidget()
        self.dockerWidget = QWidget()
        
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()             
        self.widget = QWidget()                 
        self.grid = QGridLayout()               
        
        for i in range(1,50):
            for j in range(1,5):
                object = QPushButton("btn" + str(i) + ";" + str(j))
                self.grid.addWidget(object,i,j)
        
        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.scroll)
        
        self.dockerWidget.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 100)
        self.docker.setWidget(self.dockerWidget)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(QTextEdit())
        
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea,self.docker)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo=DockWindow()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I saw
[PyQt QScrollArea within QScrollArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583927/pyqt-qscrollarea-within-qscrollarea)
but this is in PyQt4 and when I tried to convert it to PyQt5, nothing was visible again.
I also saw
[Qscrollbar in PyQt5 nothing is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994591/qscrollbar-in-pyqt5-nothing-is-shown)
but I do have a size in my code for the QScrollArea.

So how can I make the buttons visible?

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. Remove `self.dockerWidget` and its layout, and just use `self.docker.setWidget(self.scroll)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that works.
Code is now:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pprint import pprint

class DockWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DockWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout=QHBoxLayout()
    
        self.docker = QDockWidget()
    
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()             
        self.widget = QWidget()                 
        self.grid = QGridLayout()               
    
        for i in range(1,50):
            for j in range(1,5):
                object = QPushButton("btn" + str(i) + ";" + str(j))
                self.grid.addWidget(object,i,j)
    
        self.widget.setLayout(self.grid)

        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.docker.setWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 100)
    
        self.setCentralWidget(QTextEdit())
    
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea,self.docker)
        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo=DockWindow()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```